# Regex pattern issue with single character

Tags: regex, email-validation

I have a regex for emails validation and it goes like this:

```
[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-]?)+[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}
```

But some users with a single letter after the `@` character email can not be validated. For instance: `testemail@t.com` is not valid.

I'm not sure how to change the regex to allow this validation as well.

By checking it, this part here `@([A-Za-z0-9]` should already allow setting at least one character after `@` but it doesn't. If I put like at least 2 letters then the email is validated. For instance: `testemail@tt.com` is valid.

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: [Why craft your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378)?

Comment: Your pattern enforces at least ***two*** characters. That is because `([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-]?)+` will require at least one, and followed by `[A-Za-z0-9]+` which requires another character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this way
`[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-]?)*[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}`

Comment: An explanation could be nice... Especially considering you only changed a single character from the original pattern...

Comment: Thank you, now I will try to help people with a step-by-step explanation